# interior of dryer is scratching clothes

Tags: dryer

Several of my nice dry fit shirts have come out of the dryer with snags on them recently. Upon inspection, there are many sharp edges on the inside of my dryer. I think what happened was that a pocketknife recently was in my pants during a dryer cycle and it caused all kinds of dings and scratches to the inside of my dryer, which makes total sense.

So the question is how do I fix this? The drum/inner tub is all scratched up, on the back and probably the front door as well. But otherwise the dryer works perfectly well. I would prefer to not have to purchase a new dryer but I also cannot keep putting my clothes through torture and at least partially ruining several of them just to get them dry.  Please help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: I ordered some Sucru, so I hope that will do the trick. Dryers only get up to 135 and once set, Sucru is supposed to be able to handle 185

Comment: Could you string a cloths line?

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I do hang dry some things but that would be a pain to do it for everything. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how damaged the inside is, I would just use sandpaper to smooth the rough spots. If you find very bad nick, you could file it first and then hit it with sand paper.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea. I'll try that before the Sucru and maybe the 2 together along with using dryer bags will make extra sure that my clothes are safe.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the material of the drum so I assume it is not Stainless Steel.

> Are you sure of the problem - because sometimes the lining around the
>   drum at the opening itself wears and allows clothes to get snagged
>   between drum and frame.

If it really is the drum you could replace the drum with a new drum, or Replace the dryer with a unit that has a Stainless Steel tub. I know it is a bit more $$ wise but things like knives and such are not going to simply cut into it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know it is not stainless since it is magnetic. I felt around inside and felt several sharp holes so I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: @DanCsharpster    Your tub can be magnetic even if it is stainless steel (Low grade Stainless is magnetic - also some manufacturers plate the metal in a stainless plating process you will find that on modern appliances.  A metal tub that is scratched and cut - that must be one serious pocket knife. As one poster suggested sanding - you can then come back over that with a polishing compound.